# mvc4 razor rendering validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-validation

Validation rendering issue

I have in my model these data annotations:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adres is een verplicht veld")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string D_Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Huisnummer is verplicht")]
    public int D_AddressNumber { get; set; }

    public string D_AddressExtra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CapacityRate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is een verplicht veld")]
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string D_Zipcode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Plaats is een verpicht veld")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string D_City { get; set; }
```

in my cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D_Address, new { @class = "span6" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D_AddressNumber, new { @class = "span2" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D_AddressExtra, new { @class = "span2" })
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.D_Address, null, new { @class = "label label-important" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.D_AddressNumber, null, new { @class = "label label-important" })
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D_Zipcode, new { @class = "span4" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.D_Zipcode, null, new { @class = "label label-important" })
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D_City, new { @class = "span4" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.D_City, null, new { @class = "label label-important" })
    <br />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Versturen" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
}
```

on my local machine it renders like:

```
<form action="/validatie/quoterequest" method="post">

<input class="span6" data-val="true" data-val-required="Adres is een verplicht veld"     id="D_Address" name="D_Address" type="text" value="" />

<input class="span2" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field D_AddressNumber must be a number." data-val-required="Huisnummer is verplicht" id="D_AddressNumber" name="D_AddressNumber" type="text" value="" />

<input class="span2" id="D_AddressExtra" name="D_AddressExtra" type="text" value="" /><br />
<span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_Address" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_AddressNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br />

<input class="span4" data-val="true" data-val-required="Postcode is een verplicht veld" id="D_Zipcode" name="D_Zipcode" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_Zipcode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br />
<input class="span4" data-val="true" data-val-required="Plaats is een verpicht veld" id="D_City" name="D_City" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br />

<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Versturen" class="btn btn-primary" /><br />
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul>
<li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>

</form>
```

on my server :

```
<form action="/Validatie/Quoterequest" method="post">

<input class="span6" id="D_Address" name="D_Address" type="text" value="" />

<input class="span2" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field D_AddressNumber must be a number." data-val-required="Huisnummer is verplicht" id="D_AddressNumber" name="D_AddressNumber" type="text" value="" />

<input class="span2" id="D_AddressExtra" name="D_AddressExtra" type="text" value="" />    <br /> <span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_Address" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_AddressNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br /> 

<input class="span4" id="D_Zipcode" name="D_Zipcode" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_Zipcode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br /> 

<input class="span4" id="D_City" name="D_City" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid label label-important" data-valmsg-for="D_City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    <br />     

<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Versturen" class="btn btn-primary" />     <br /> 
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li> </ul></div>

</form>
```

I also have this information 
Local machine
IISVersion :`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

```
 ProcesVersionInfo : File: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe InternalName: iisexpress.exe 
OriginalFilename: iisexpress.exe.mui 
FileVersion: 8.0.8418.0 (winmain(eokim).120521-1311) 



FileDescription: IIS Express Worker Process
 Product: Internet Information Services 
ProductVersion: 8.0.8418.0 
Debug: False
 Patched: False 
PreRelease: False 
PrivateBuild: True 
SpecialBuild: False 
Language: Language Neutral
```

**On the server**:
`IISVersion : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

```
ProcesVersionInfo : File: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
InternalName: w3wp.exe OriginalFilename: w3wp.exe.mui 
FileVersion: 7.5.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) 
FileDescription: IIS Worker Process Product: Internet Information Services ProductVersion: 7.5.7600.16385
 Debug: False
 Patched: False
 PreRelease: False 
PrivateBuild: False 
SpecialBuild: False 
Language: Taalonafhankelijk
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar symptoms in Windows7 x64 MVC4 in VS2010.  The code was not rendering data-val attributes even in simple forms.

I have now solved it!

To debug, first try to create a strongly typed "Edit" View using your model and the Add>View menu option.  See if the properties you are expecting show up in the View that is created.  If not, and like me you find that no fields are automatically added, your problem is the model definition.

You probably have something like...

```
public class MyModel 
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "or else!")]

     public string My_Broken_DataValEmittingProperty;
}
```

You need to modify it to be:

```
public class MyModel 
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "or else!")]

     public string My_Working_DataValEmittingProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now, **REBUILD YOUR SOLUTION** and try Add>View again.  Remember this works using Reflection, so it needs this compiled into the DLL.  If that worked, you will also find you now get data-val attributes from EditorFor methods.

Given you are copying DLLs to a server environment, does your source code actually represent the compiled DLLs you believe you are deploying?  I would recompile both Debug and Release versions, test both locally, then copy the release versions over to the server.

--

Notwithstanding, the process I have gone through may help you debug further.
I originally assumed it was jQuery versioning or event issue, so made the following mods and checks:
1) web.config - both ClientVlidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled are true.
2) These attributes are in the correct web.config file - the outermost one
3) Simplified views to avoid use of bundles altogether - bundles can re-order files
4) Downgraded jQuery to the default version as shipped with MVC4
5) Simplifed forms to avoid using partials - partials can lack a formContext which causes the same issue
6) Explicitly referenced jQuery, jQuery.validate, and jQuery.validate.unobtrusive in that order in the _Layout.cshtml file.
7) Checked rendered HTML in FireBug, and not relied on viewing source in the browser
My project is an MVC3 upgrade to MVC4, so I imported all custom files into a virgin MVC4 project, to ensure I had not missed anything.  I am convinced the answer lies in isolating why data-val attributes are not rendered by design in the EditorFor methods.  Code comments say:

```
// Only render attributes if unobtrusive client-side validation is enabled, and then
// only if we've never rendered validation for a field with this name in this form. 
// Also, if there's no form context, then we can't render the attributes (we'd have no
// <form> to attach them to).
```

Remember that these are Helper methods.  So as a workaround, you can hand type the output of the "helper" method into the view, and save a lot of time.

Best of luck!